# function that returns a consumer of T type, over inheriting classes

Tags: java

I have an interface `Sendable<T>`, that has a method `Consumer<T> getSave()`. `PIDConfigurable` is an interface that extends `Sendable` with `PIDCoefs` as the parameter. Then there's `PIDFConfigurable` that extends `PIDConfigureable`. I can't seem to manage to have the function `getSave` return a consumer with the type `PIDCoefs` in the first interface, and `PIDFCoefs` in the second one. There's a clash between both interfaces, as the method has different return types in each interface. How can I make this work, as the type of the first function is a parent (of sort) of the type of the second interface?

The highlighted line of code at the end is where I get the error, that `getSave()` in `PIDFConfigurable` is clashing with the method with the same name in `PIDConfigurable`.

```java
public interface Saveable<T> {
    Supplier<? extends T> getLoad();

    Consumer<? super T> getSave();
}


public interface PIDConfigurable extends Saveable<PIDCoefs> {
    @Override
    Supplier<? extends PIDCoefs> getLoad();

    @Override
    Consumer<? super PIDCoefs> getSave();
}

public interface PIDFConfigurable extends PIDConfigurable, Saveable<PIDCoefs> {

    @Override
    Supplier<PIDFCoefs> getLoad();

    @Override
    *Consumer<PIDFCoefs> getSave();*
}
```

Comment: Can you show some code? That is, a [mcve] of the error that you get?

Comment: You seem to have got the inheritance relationship the other way around. If `PIDFCoefs` inherits from `PIDCoefs`, then `PIDConfigureable` should inherit `PIDFConfigurable`, not: `PIDFConfigurable` inherits `PIDConfigureable`.

Comment: @Sweeper, that's the way it is, sorry if I wasn't clear enough about it.

Comment: That's why you should [edit] your question to include some code!

Comment: @Sweeper yep you're right, I added some code, I hope it clarifies the issue a bit.

Comment: Well this just isn't type safe at all. That's like trying to override a method that is supposed to return a `Dog` with a method that return can return any `Animal`. `Consumer<PIDFCoefs>` is not a kind of `Consumer<? super PIDCoefs>`, in the same way that a consumer of dogs, is not a kind of consumer of *any animal*.

Comment: On the other hand, `getLoad` works because `Supplier<PIDFCoefs>` is a kind of `Supplier<? extends PIDCoefs>`, in the same way that a supplier of dogs, *is* a kind of "supplier of animals". You should rethink your design.

Comment: @Sweeper Do you have an idea that keeps `Saveable` generic and PIDF classes inherit from PID classes?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242208/discussion-between-lavi-arzi-and-sweeper).